# Composite Primary Key and @OneToOne JPA - Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

My entities are as follows

Office

```
@Entity
public class Office {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private int latitude;
    private int longitude;
    private String buildingName;
    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Point - which is an `EmbeddedId`

```
@Embeddable
public class Point implements Serializable {

    private int latitude;
    private int longitude;
    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Location

```
@Entity
public class Location {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Point point;
    private String country;

    @OneToOne // How to add a OneToOne Mapping
    private Office office;
    // getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Question:
I want to add a one-to-one mapping between the `Office` and the `Location` entity.

What I've tried:
I added the following annotations along with `@OneToOne` mapping in the `Location` entity

```
@JoinColumn(name = "latitude", referencedColumnName = "latitude")
@JoinColumn(name = "longitude", referencedColumnName = "longitude")
```

but I got the following error

```
Provided id of the wrong type for class com.example.demo.entity.employee.o2m_cpk.Office. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class com.example.demo.entity.employee.o2m_cpk.Point
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following mappings:

```java
@Entity
public class Office {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "office")
    private Location location;
    private String buildingName;
}

@Embeddable
public class Point implements Serializable {

    private int latitude;
    private int longitude;
}

@Entity
public class Location {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Point point;
    private String country;

    @OneToOne
    private Office office;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Could you please tell me how the mapping should be if I want to make `Location` entity the owning side?

Comment: Updated the code sample in my answer.